# Passwordless rsync while requiring key and password for all other access

Tags: ssh, rsync, openssh

I have a server set up to require public-key authentication for ssh access using a key with a password. Is there a way to set up a password-less key that will only be allowed when executing rsync over ssh, while still requiring the key and password for all other ssh access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate RSA key just for rsync to use.  Do not put a passphrase on that key.  Give it a unique name, such as `id_rsa_rsync` for the private key and `id_rsa_rsync.pub` for the public key.

On the server, install the public key on a new line of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, like this:

```
(server)$ cat << EOF >> .ssh/authorized_keys
command="rsync",no-pty,no-port-forwarding (paste your public key here)
EOF
```

Check the resulting file to make sure it looks sort of like this:

```
(server)$ tail -1 .ssh/authorized_keys
command="rsync",no-pty,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAB3..blah..blah..HhcvQ== you@example.com
```

When you want to `rsync` from your local machine to the server, you will need to add `-e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync'` to tell `rsync` to use the new key you just set up:

```
rsync -av -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync' local/files* server:/remote/path/
```

With some clever entries in your `~/.ssh/config` file, you can simplify the `rsync` command line:

```
# this entry is used for normal logins to "server":
Host server
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

# this entry is used for rsyncing to "server" without a passphrase:
Host server-rsync
  Hostname server
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_rsync
```

The `Hostname server` line needs to specify a valid DNS name or `/etc/hosts` entry.  With that config entry in place, your `rsync` command line becomes just:

```
rsync -av local/files* server-rsync:/remote/path/
```

Comment: So, per your last point,  if I set up config in .ssh, I don't have to even tell rsync directly to use ssh, but it will look in the .ssh/config file automatically and use that?

Comment: Yes, if I understand you correctly.  rsync uses ssh by default.  But by default, ssh uses your **normal** key, which requires a passphrase.  But if you set up the .ssh/config file, and then use the special hostname "server-rsync" (or one of your own choosing) in the rsync command line, then ssh will use the new key that does not require a passphrase.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, then I discovered this method will allow executing rsync [b]on the server[/b] using the password-less key. I'm trying to use rsync on my local host to copy files to the server and I wasn't clear on that in my question. It put me on the right track, though, for an alternative. Thanks!